# skrollr.js parallax issue bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css, parallax

I'm using skrollr.js for parallax effect on desktop. It works perfectly until it hits the end of the page and the last parallax is just zoomed after the footer and goes full screen. I just want the site to end at the footer. you can take a look at it.

http://demmerav.com/adi/

Did anyone face this issue before

This is the code I used for parallax

```
 <div class="parallax">
      <section id="slide-7" class="homeSlide" data-bottom="opacity: 0;" data--5p-bottom="opacity: 1;" data-anchor-target="#slide-7">
            <div class="bcg" data-top=" width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0%; left: 0%;" data-80p-bottom=" width: 140%; height: 140%; top: -20%; left: -20%; " data-anchor-target="#slide-6">
            </div>
          <div class="plaxEl" data-top=" position: fixed; top: 206px; width: 100%; left: 0;" data-center="" data-10p-bottom="" data-bottom="opacity: 0;" data-anchor-target="#slide-7">

          </div> 
        </section>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.bcg {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 480px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border-top:10px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    border-bottom:10px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    z-index: -1;
}

#slide-7 .bcg {
    background-image:url('../images/parallax/parallax-7.jpg');
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance